# angular unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a code that was working fine and suddenly an error appeared in angular saying:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at Object.parse (native)
at fromJson (http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:1250:14)
at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:9371:16)
at http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:9462:12
at forEach (http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:336:20)
at transformData (http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:9461:3)
at transformResponse (http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:10241:23)
at processQueue (http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:14634:28)
at http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:14650:27
at Scope.parent.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost/public_html/faculte/js/angular.js:15878:28)
```

In my code i'm sending a http request to PHP and here's the JS code:

```
main.submitNewChap = function(){
    var data = main.newChap;
    data.function = 'submitNewChap';
    $http({
        url: "ajax-functions.php",
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike(data)
    }).success(function(res) {
        switch(res.msg){
            case 1:
                $translate(['success','newChapSuccess']).then(function(t){
                    toastr.success(t.newChapSuccess,t.success);
                });
                main.newChap = {};
                main.data.chaps.push(res.item);
                break;
            case 2:
                $translate(['error','missingData']).then(function (t) {
                    toastr.error(t.missingData,t.error);
                });
                break;
            case 3:
                $translate(['error','notAllowed']).then(function (t) {
                    toastr.error(t.notAllowed,t.error);
                });
                break;
        }
    }).error(function(res) {
        $translate(['error','generalError']).then(function (t) {
            toastr.error(t.generalError,t.error);
        });
    });
}
```

And the PHP function:

```
function submitNewChap($data){
$res = 0;
$item = array();
if(userData('role') == 'admin'){
    if($data['title'] != ''){
        $item = R::dispense('chap');
        $item->title = $data['title'];
        $item->date = time();
        $id = R::store($item);
        $res = 1;
        $item = array(
            'id' => $id,
            'title' => $item->title,
            'date' => $item->date,
            'courses' => array()
        );
    }else{
        $res = 2;
    }
}else{
    $hack = R::dispense('hack');
    $hack->text = "Trying to hack and adding Chap";
    R::store($hack);
    $res = 3;
}
return array(
    'msg' => $res,
    'item' => $item
);
/*
1: ok
2: missing data
3: not allowed
*/
```

}

And this is my ajax-functions.php code:

```
include 'functions.php';
if(isset($_POST['function'])){
switch ($_POST['function']) {
    case 'submitNewChap':
    echo json_encode(submitNewChap($_POST));
    default:
        break;
}
}
```

I find no error in my code (at least, I think) and I searched everywhere but I didn't find any solution on web, what's the problem ?

Comment: The problem with server response. Can you post it?

Comment: This seems to be a issue with the fact that you aren't returning JSON, you are returning php code, which is not JSON encoded, thus it parses wrong. Also you aren't putting in the header in php. If you do all that, show us in code please.

Comment: I edited the message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to right-click in the Developer Tools console, and click "Enable XMLHttpRequest logging".

Once it is enabled, you will see the XHR (ajax) requests in the console, and will be able to click on them to take you to the resources panel, where you'll be able to see the content/response of your request.

if there was a php error in your request, you can see the error details there.

this is not an answer. this should be a comment. but as u can see, i am a newbie here.

Comment: even if this should be a comment I mark it as best answer! it helped me a lot to resolve my problem! I was missing 'break;' in my php... thanks a lot

Comment: @Burawi glad that helped you.